# How to find path with Zendframework3?

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, zend-framework3, php-7.1

I am using zendframework3 with nginad on ubuntu16, the index page is showing, but when I click on signup, add publisher etc. It couldn't find the route. I looked at the folder structure and configuration files as well as views it's there, but couldn't find out what's wrong. Here is the path:
  /signup/customer
  /signup/newuser
  /auth/login
  /company
  /legal

```
Here is the configure file for DashboardManager module:
<?php


return array(
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'websites' => array(
                'type'    => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                        'route'    =>  
 '/websites[/[:action[/[:param1[/]]]]]',
                        'defaults' => array(
                                'controller' => 
'DashboardManager\Controller\Website',
                                'action'     => 'index',
                        ),
                ),
        ),
        'users' => array(
                'type'    => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                        'route'    =>  '/users[/[:action[/[:param1[/]]]]]',
                        'defaults' => array(
                                'controller' => 
'DashboardManager\Controller\Signup',
                                'action'     => 'account',
                        ),
                ),
        ),
        'pxsspdirectory' => array(
                'type'    => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                        'route'    =>  
'/directory[/[:action[/[:param1[/]]]]]',
                        'constraints' => array(
                                'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                'param1'     => '[0-9]+',
                        ),
                        'defaults' => array(
                                '__NAMESPACE__' => 
'DashboardManager\Controller',
                                'controller' => 
'DashboardManager\Controller\Services',
                                'action'     => 'ssp',
                        ),
                ),
        ),
        'pxpublishers' => array(
                'type'    => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                        'route'    =>  '/private-
 exchange/publishers/websites[/]',
                        'defaults' => array(
                                'controller' => 
'DashboardManager\Controller\Publisher',
                                'action'     => 'pxpublishers',
                        ),
                ),
        ),
        'pxpublisherslist' => array(
                'type'    => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                        'route'    =>  '/private-
 exchange/websites/list/[:param1[/]]',
                        'defaults' => array(
                                'controller' => 
'DashboardManager\Controller\Website',
                                'action'     => 'pxlist',
                        ),
                ),
        ),
        'pxwebsitelist' => array(
                'type'    => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                        'route'    =>  '/private-
 exchange/publisher/websites[/]',
                        'defaults' => array(
                                'controller' => ' 
 DashboardManager\Controller\Website',
                                'action'     => 'pxwebsitelist',
                        ),
                ),
        ),
        'pxnewpublisher' => array(
                'type'    => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                        'route'    =>  '/private-
 exchange/publishers/add[/]',
                        'defaults' => array(
                                'controller' => 
'DashboardManager\Controller\Signup',
                                'action'     => 'pxnewpublisher',
                        ),
                ),
        ),
        'pxloginaspublisher' => array(
                'type'    => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                        'route'    =>  '/private-
 exchange/publishers/loginasdomain[/]',
                        'defaults' => array(
                                'controller' => 
'DashboardManager\Controller\Publisher',
                                'action'     => 'loginasdomain',
                        ),
                ),
        ),
        'pxpublisherlist' => array(
                'type'    => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                        'route'    =>  '/private-
exchange/publishers/list[/]',
                        'defaults' => array(
                                'controller' => 
'DashboardManager\Controller\Signup',
                                'action'     => 'publishersdomain',
                        ),
                ),
        ),
        'pxnewpublisheradd' => array(
                'type'    => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                        'route'    =>  '/private-
 exchange/publishers/new[/]',
                        'defaults' => array(
                                '__NAMESPACE__' => 
 'DashboardManager\Controller',
                                'controller' => 
 'DashboardManager\Controller\Signup',
                                'action'     => 'pxnewuser',
                        ),
                ),
        ),
        'company' => array(
                'type'    => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                        'route'    =>  '/company',
                        'defaults' => array(
                                'controller' => 
'DashboardManager\Controller\Company',
                                'action'     => 'index',
                        ),
                ),

                'may_terminate' => true,
                'child_routes' => array(
                   'action' => array(
                         'type' => 'segment',
                         'options' => array(
                                'route'    =>  '/:action',
                                'constraints' => array(
                                        //'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                        'param1'     => '[0-9]+',
                                ),
                                'defaults' => array(
                                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'DashboardManager\Controller',
                                        'controller' => 'DashboardManager\Controller\Company',
                                        'action'     => 'index',
                                ),
                         ),
                    ),
                    'press' => array(
                         'type' => 'segment',
                         'options' => array(
                                'route'    =>  '/press/releases/:param1',
                                'constraints' => array(
                                        //'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                        'param1'     => '[0-9]+',
                                ),
                                'defaults' => array(
                                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'DashboardManager\Controller',
                                        'controller' => 'DashboardManager\Controller\Company',
                                        'action'     => 'pressinner',
                                ),
                         ),
                    ),
                    'jobs' => array(
                         'type' => 'segment',
                         'options' => array(
                                'route'    =>  '/jobs/post/:param1',
                                'constraints' => array(
                                        //'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                        'param1'     => '[0-9]+',
                                ),
                                'defaults' => array(
                                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'DashboardManager\Controller',
                                        'controller' => 'DashboardManager\Controller\Company',
                                        'action'     => 'jobsinner',
                                ),
                         ),
                    ),
                    'jobform' => array(
                         'type' => 'segment',
                         'options' => array(
                                'route'    =>  '/jobs/post/apply/:param1',
                                'constraints' => array(
                                        //'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                        'param1'     => '[0-9]+',
                                ),
                                'defaults' => array(
                                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'DashboardManager\Controller',
                                        'controller' => 'DashboardManager\Controller\Company',
                                        'action'     => 'jobform',
                                ),
                         ),
                    ),
                ),
        ),
        'signup' => array(
                'type'    => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                        'route'    =>  '/signup[/[:action[/[:param1[/]]]]]',
                        'constraints' => array(
                                'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                'param1'     => '[0-9]+',
                        ),
                        'defaults' => array(
                                '__NAMESPACE__' => 'DashboardManager\Controller',
                                'controller' => 'DashboardManager\Controller\Signup',
                                'action'     => 'index',
                        ),
                ),
        ),
        'signup-index' => array(
                'type'    => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                        'route'    =>  '/',
                        'constraints' => array(
                                'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                'param1'     => '[0-9]+',
                        ),
                        'defaults' => array(
                                '__NAMESPACE__' => 'DashboardManager\Controller',
                                'controller' => 'DashboardManager\Controller\Signup',
                                'action'     => 'index',
                        ),
                ),
        ),
        'manager' => array(
                'type'    => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                        'route'    =>  '/manager[/[:action[/[:param1[/]]]]]',
                        'constraints' => array(
                                'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                'param1'     => '[0-9]+',
                        ),
                        'defaults' => array(
                                '__NAMESPACE__' => 'DashboardManager\Controller',
                                'controller' => 'DashboardManager\Controller\Manager',
                                'action'     => 'index',
                        ),
                ),
        ),
        'report' => array(
                'type'    => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                        'route'    =>  '/report[/[:action[/[:param1[/]]]]]',
                        'constraints' => array(
                                'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                'param1'     => '[0-9]+',
                        ),
                        'defaults' => array(
                                '__NAMESPACE__' => 'DashboardManager\Controller',
                                'controller' => 'DashboardManager\Controller\Report',
                                'action'     => 'index',
                        ),
                ),
        ),
        'private-exchange' => array(
                'type'    => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                        'route'    =>  '/private-exchange[/[:action[/[:param1[/]]]]]',
                        'constraints' => array(
                                'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                'param1'     => '[0-9]+',
                        ),
                        'defaults' => array(
                                '__NAMESPACE__' => 'DashboardManager\Controller',
                                'controller' => 'DashboardManager\Controller\Demand',
                                'action'     => 'index',
                        ),
                ),
        ),
        'publisher' => array(
                'type'    => 'Literal',
                'options' => array(
                        'route'    =>  '/publisher',
                        'defaults' => array(
                                'controller' => 'DashboardManager\Controller\Publisher',
                                'action'     => 'index',
                        ),
                ),
                'may_terminate' => true,
                'child_routes' => array(
                    'process' => array(
                         'type' => 'segment',
                         'options' => array(
                                'route'    =>  '/[:action[/[:param1[/]]]]',
                                'constraints' => array(
                                        'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                        'param1'     => '[0-9]+',
                                ),
                                'defaults' => array(
                                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'DashboardManager\Controller',
                                        'controller' => 'DashboardManager\Controller\Publisher',
                                        'action'     => 'index',
                                ),
                         ),
                    ),
                    'zone' => array(
                         'type' => 'segment',
                         'options' => array(
                               'route' => '/zone/:param1[/[:action[/[:id[/]]]]]',
                               'constraints' => array(
                                     'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                     'param1' => '[0-9]+',
                                     'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                               ),
                               'defaults' => array(
                                      '__NAMESPACE__' => 'DashboardManager\Controller',
                                      'controller' => 'DashboardManager\Controller\Zone',
                                      'action'     => 'index',
                               ),
                          ),
                    ),
                ),
        ),
        'login' => array(
                'type'    => 'Literal',
                'options' => array(
                        'route'    => '/auth',
                        'defaults' => array(
                                'controller' => 'DashboardManager\Controller\Auth',
                                'action'        => 'login',
                        ),
                ),
                'may_terminate' => true,
                'child_routes' => array(
                        'process' => array(
                                'type'    => 'Segment',
                                'options' => array(
                                        'route'    => '/[:action]',
                                        'constraints' => array(
                                                'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                                'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                        ),
                                        'defaults' => array(
                                        ),
                                ),
                        ),
                ),
        ),
        'msa' => array(
                'type'    => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                        'route'    =>  '/auth/msa[/[:param1[/]]]',
                        'constraints' => array(
                                'param1' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        ),
                        'defaults' => array(
                                'controller' => 'DashboardManager\Controller\Auth',
                                'action'     => 'msa',
                        ),
                ),
        ),
    ),
),
'service_manager' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'translator' => 'Zend\I18n\Translator\TranslatorServiceFactory',
        'Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService' => function($sm) {
            //return new Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService(); // Built-in ZF2 Authentication Service.
            return $sm->get('AuthService'); // Custom Authentication Service.
        },
    ),
),
'translator' => array(
    'locale' => 'en_US',
    'translation_file_patterns' => array(
        array(
            'type'     => 'gettext',
            'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../language',
            'pattern'  => '%s.mo',
        ),
    ),
),
'controllers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'DashboardManager\Controller\Company' => 'DashboardManager\Controller\CompanyController',          
        'DashboardManager\Controller\Signup' => 'DashboardManager\Controller\SignupController',
        'DashboardManager\Controller\Manager' => 'DashboardManager\Controller\ManagerController',
        'DashboardManager\Controller\Demand' => 'DashboardManager\Controller\DemandController',
        'DashboardManager\Controller\Publisher' => 'DashboardManager\Controller\PublisherController',
        'DashboardManager\Controller\Auth' => 'DashboardManager\Controller\AuthController',
        'DashboardManager\Controller\Success' => 'DashboardManager\Controller\SuccessController',
        'DashboardManager\Controller\Report' => 'DashboardManager\Controller\ReportController',
        'DashboardManager\Controller\Zone' => 'DashboardManager\Controller\ZoneController',
        'DashboardManager\Controller\Website' => 'DashboardManager\Controller\WebsiteController',
        'DashboardManager\Controller\Services' => 'DashboardManager\Controller\ServicesController'
    ),
),
'view_manager' => array(
    'display_not_found_reason' => true,
    'display_exceptions'       => true,
    'doctype'                  => 'HTML5',
    'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
    'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
    'template_map' => array(
        'layout/layout'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
        'application/index/index' => __DIR__ . '/../view/application/index/index.phtml',
        'error/404'               => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
        'unauthorized_template'   => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/403.phtml',
        'error/index'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
    ),
    'template_path_stack' => array(
                __DIR__ . '/../view',
//            'manager' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
//            'private-exchange' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
     )
);
?>
```

Comment: .htaccess mistake maybe? Can you confirm you got right path in index.php?

Comment: Yes, I saw it in the source page, I don't have .htacess since I use nginx and the web root folder points to /upload/public/index.php, the module is under /upload/module/DashboardManager, there's application.config under /upload/config and init_autoloader under upload, wish I didn't mess it with previous zendframe, thanks!

Comment: As you know, url you typed is not important. All access requests goes to index.php which is you will build freamwork and let it route. If url you requested is not accessible via freamwork, you will see freamwork's `not found` page. If you see  this page its miss-configuration. Otherwise you can not access index.php.

Comment: Also for routes which has sub routes have to `may_terminate` key as `true` otherwise they will not match by router.

Comment: Here is the index/config files  https://github.com/nginadofficial/nginad/blob/master/upload/public/index.php https://github.com/nginadofficial/nginad/blob/master/upload/config/application.config.php @MehmetSÖĞÜNMEZ